# UITextView's NSTextContainer wrong position on text view height NSLayoutConstraint change

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, nstextcontainer

I have subclassed `UITextView` to make it return an intrinsic content size like this:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(self.bounds.size, [self intrinsicContentSize])) {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    /*
     Intrinsic content size of a textview is UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
     We have to build what we want here: contentSize + textContainerInset should do the trick
     */
    CGSize intrinsicContentSize = self.contentSize;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f) {
        intrinsicContentSize.width += (self.textContainerInset.left + self.textContainerInset.right ) / 2.0f;
        intrinsicContentSize.height += (self.textContainerInset.top + self.textContainerInset.bottom) / 2.0f;
    }

    return intrinsicContentSize;
}
```

I have added an observer to the `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification` and when the text view content change I update its height to make it growth with the text height:

```
- (void)textViewTextDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)notification.object;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    void (^animationBlock)() = ^
    {
        self.messageInputViewHeightConstraint.constant = MAX(0, self.messageInputView.intrinsicContentSize.height);
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:animationBlock
                     completion:nil];
}
```

But when their is enough lines to fill the text view height, half of the time when a new line is added the NSTextContainer of the UITextView is not well placed like you can see in this picture

[image]

(The NSTextContainer is outlined in red and UITextView is outlined in blue)
The other half of the time when a new line is added the NSTextContainer is replaced correctly.

I did not found how to solve this weird behavior.
I hope one of you will have an answer to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: did you solve this problem? if so how did you fix it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33695569/727429